# Can't seem to access cookie in Python (2.4)

Tags: python, cookies, cgi

I have a CGI script for which I've successfully set a cookie (which I can see in Firefox/Chrome!) which has (say) the name uid and the content 1. I don't seem to understand how to access this cookie from another CGI script--and I'm working in Python 2.4 so a lot of the examples I've found may not apply.

This code prints "can't get uid" followed by the rest of the page:

```
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE"))
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print c.output()
print("\n\n")
uid = c.get("uid")
#uid = c["uid"].value # this would create an error and page would fail totally
if uid is None: 
    print("can't get uid")
    uid = 1 # set manually to prevent the rest of the page from failing
```

I haven't done anything fishy with the domain the cookie applies to, so I don't understand why this doesn't grab the uid value. By the way, if I try to print c.output(), it's blank.

Comment: Hello again. What do you see in Firefox's cookie view?

Comment: I have 3 cookies in Firefox for the domain in question. One is named __utma and the content is a string of numbers. One is named lastvisit and the value is a Unix timestamp. The last is named uid and the content is a single digit--the UID as set correctly from the login.cgi script.

Comment: I realize there's something unrealistic about the way I'm testing this. In the browser, I just get a nonspecific "Server error" page. If I test it on the command line, I'm getting that "can't get uid" message... but on the command line, there's no browser so actually I shouldn't expect it to be able to fetch the cookie! So this problem is harder than I thought--the error could be anywhere in the file. I'm going to try to make a really simple one now that doesn't nothing but try to access the cookie.

Comment: What does `os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE")` contain in the first place?

Comment: Good question--in my new little test script, it prints "__utma=57748789.1760654691.1241999324.1241999324.1241999324.1; lastvisit=1292457040.65; uid=1; __utma=57748789.1760654691.1241999324.1241999324.1241999324.1" Don't know why the one part is repeated twice. But even with that info, neither uid = c.get("uid") nor uid = c["uid"].value gives me a value I can print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured this out! I confirmed that os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE") was getting something, and then played with the order of the elements in my tiny test until it worked. Then I reproduced that order in my more complicated script. (Specifically: content type declaration, two newlines, get cookie, get value from cookie, everything else.)

The main thing I've learned about Python and CGI is that the order of elements (starting with the content type declaration) is very fussy. Thanks very much for the hints in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is are you sure the webserver or the framework is setting the `HTTP_COOKIE` environment variable?
Otherwise, in one of your script you may want to store the cookies in the CookieJar file in the file system and access the set cookies from there.

```
import cookielib

COOKIEFILE = 'Cookies.lwp'
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cookiejar.load(COOKIEFILE)
cookiejar["uid"] = 1
cookiejar.save(COOKIEFILE)
```

Load the same cookiejar and do the get of uid in the other script.